# C# get pwdLastSet from AD

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory, mahapps.metro

I tried get "pwdLastSet" from AD but have problem with data convert.

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + Login + "))";
ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
SearchResult rs = ds.FindOne();

if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["samaccountname"].Value == null)
{
    var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MetroWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (window != null)
        await window.ShowMessageAsync("error!", "error");
    return;
}
else
{
        TextBox_Password.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Here, I get: System.__ComObject

I also tried:

```
long value = (long)rs.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0];
DateTime pwdLastSet = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(value);
value = long.Parse(TextBox_Password.Text);
```

Here, I get Exception: Incorrect input string format

Comment: @mjwills TextBox_Password.Text is return date from AD. Exception is from catch when i debug.

Comment: In first case: System.__ComObject Second: Nothing

Comment: In TextBox_Password.Text i want return date from AD. There's nothing there or System.__ComObject Second.  What can I type here when i want date in this textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `TextBox_Password.Text` property to a string representation of the retrieved date and not call `long.Parse`:

```
long value = (long)rs.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0];
DateTime pwdLastSet = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(value);
TextBox_Password.Text = pwdLastSet.ToString();
```